# Bash Whiptail Gauge Progress

Tags: bash, whiptail

i want to use `whiptail --gauge` to show the current process of a User Deletion.

In this Process i will first lock them out, backing up his home, killing his Processes etc.
How could i use `whiptail --gauge` that it will only be shown once and updated in every step.
Any Example i saw was with a for or while loop which is not very usable if every step is *only* a different command.

I Tried with a `{...}|whiptail...`-block for every command but that was not successfull

Comment: Current status of the code itself: https://gist.github.com/Serverfrog/6a221b972fee3e5bfd11f02630c157ea

Comment: How about **command1; echo 10; command2; echo 20; command3; echo 30; ...** ? I have never used whiptail, but it's documentation seems to imply this kind of usage.

Comment: when i see something like [this](https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/whiptail-using-a-progress-gauge/) i don't think so

Comment: The docs say that whiptail reads an integer from stdin and updates the status of progress. So, if you give four integers (with some sleep in between) as 25,50,75,100, then it must show progress in jumps of 25% points at a time. It doesn't seem to need a for/while loop from the developer. As long as you can pipe four numbers (or some bunch of numbers) into whiptail (with some intervening sleeps or actual commands), the whiptail should work.

Comment: Try this **{ echo 25; sleep 2; echo 50; sleep 2; echo 50; sleep 2; echo 100; } | whiptail --backtitle "Demo" --title "Progress" --gauge "Processing ..." 6 70 0**. If it doesn't work, it may be because we need flush at end of each echo statement. Also whiptail seem to depend heavily on TERM and its associated properties.

Comment: Then the Process of execution and the whiptail process would be in different bash's because of the pipe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123898/discussion-between-blackpen-and-serverfrog).